# Solve arc integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Solve
$$\int_{AB}^{}\frac{yds}{\sqrt{x}},$$ where AB - arc $${y}^{2}=\frac{4}{9}{x}^{3}, A(3;2\sqrt{3}), B(8;\frac{32}{3}\sqrt{2})$$
I dont know how to solve this. Can you write a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remember the relation:

$$ds = \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx$$

And with the equation of the arc, you can substitute $y$ with the expression of $x$.
After this, your integral becomes a single variable integration in $x$, which is not hard to carry out.

It is better for you to try for yourself following the hint. Good luck!